# Option selection in WebDriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using WebDriver and selenium-firefox-driver version 2.3.1. Now when `option.setSelected();` deprecated, one must do `option.click();` directly or more exactly :

```
if (value.equals(option.getAttribute("value"))) {
    if(!option.isSelected()) {
        option.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I get this exception without reason.

> Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

```
<select id="deadLineDay" name="deadLineDay">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Also, it is definitely not a timing issue... Any idea what the hell is that ? The exception is thrown only sometimes, but as I say, not a timing issue, I'm debugging that

This is the code :

```
public FillOutForm(WebDriver driver, UploadDocumentPage parent) {
    this.driver = driver;
    this.parent = parent;
    PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 3), this);
}

@FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = day)
private WebElement deadLineDay;
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = hour)
private WebElement deadLineHour;
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = minute)
private WebElement deadLineMinute;
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = AmPm)
private WebElement deadLineAmPm;
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = desc)
private WebElement description;
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = comm)
private WebElement comment;

public boolean validationPasses(Map<String, String> map) {

    try {
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            WebElement we = (WebElement) this.getClass().getDeclaredField(key).get(this);
            setSelectedField(we, map.get(key));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error(e.getMessage());
    }

    valid = elementExists(driver, By.className(validatorError));

    return valid;
}

public void setSelectedField(WebElement element, String value) {
    List<WebElement> options = element.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
    for (WebElement option : options) {
        if (value.equals(option.getAttribute("value"))) {
            if(!option.isSelected()) {
                option.click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps you need to implement org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait to wait for the element (properly loaded)

Comment: I said it was not the issue ... I already tried

Comment: It processes 10 other fields on that page before it get's to the select fields. And I'm waiting 3 seconds for the fields to load up...I was 1 second before... PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 3), this);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Man it might seem hard to believe, but a month ago I often got out of space on disk and suddenly all tests were failing like this. It obviously doesn't have a reason to fail as far as I can see from the code you pasted...

Also I see you're using AjaxElementLocatorFactory. Switch to DefaultElementLocatorFactory, it might go away.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.  Try wrapping the `WebElement` with a `Select` object:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
...

public void setSelectedField(WebElement element, String value) {
    Select dropdown = new Select(element);
    dropdown.selectByVisibleText(value);
}
```

Comment: Joe this is really one of the most disgusting bugs to deal with. As Edgar answered I run the tests again. And it's back ! wrapping into Select object doesn't help. In fact when I wrap it, it doesn't find it at all.\

Comment: This way ends up in option.click(); as well, it's practically the same, convenience ....

Comment: Is the page static, or are you doing something Ajaxy?  I suspect a race condition.  If you post your markup and accompanying ECMAScript, I'll take a closer look.

Comment: The code snippets that you've provided are working; the problem is elsewhere and we need more context: any ECMAScript and stylesheets (CSS-defined visibility can be the cause).